# Python version and Anaconda

Tags: python, macos

Recently, I've installed Anaconda3 in a MacOS laptop, but I need to set back the default python version to 2.7 because of some old codes involving the following syntax:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

I read some comments and it seems like the easiest way to do it is by using an alias,

```
alias python="python2"
```

but even after setting this on my bash_profile, I'm still getting this:

```
$ which python
/anaconda3/bin/python
```

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not create an Anaconda environment instead?

Comment: @gmds sorry for my ignorance, but I'm running the codes in the terminal, without the direct intervention of Anaconda. Is that relevant for your suggestion?

Comment: As @gmds pointed out, creating a new environment is probably the easier solution since you have already installed Anaconda. It's really simple to create one and use it [link](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Comment: What I read from his question is that he needs to restore the default behavior because switching to Anaconda has broken things.  A virtual env isn't going to help with that, or is at least not IMO the way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, you don't want to use an alias to do this.  Rather, you want to manipulate your filesystem and/or PATH variable so that the first instance of a binary named 'python' found by the system on your PATH is the one you want to have running by default.

If it made sense to do so, and it was easy to do, an obvious fix would be to uninstall Anaconda.  But I assume you still need it.

You could also dig into what the Mac might be doing in your case to manage multiple Python versions in some formal way.  This might be the best solution, but I can't tell you how that works.  You could Google for that information probably. If you want to take a more basic approach, read on.

What I'd suggest you do first is run the command **ls -l `which python`**.  This will tell you which Python binary is currently the default one, and show you details about that binary.  I'm guessing that that "binary" is actually a symbolic link, pointing to some other file.  If so, you can just delete that link, or rename it to something else.  The same thing will work if what you see is not a symbolic link, but rather a real executable, but it's a bigger deal to decide to delete or rename a real executable.  If you just rename this file, you can obviously reverse what you've done any time you want.

Once you do this, do **ls -l `which python`** again.  This should give you a new answer and be pointing at the original python installation.  You can confirm which version of python is now the default by running **python**.

Comment: Can you please click the "Check Mark" to say that this answer answered your question?  Thanks